# Can we prove $\frac{1}{2}$ is positive?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

It is well known that we can prove $1>0$ using trichotomy properties of $\mathbb{R}$. Can we prove $\frac{1}{2}>0$ using trichotomy properties of $\mathbb{R}$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean the argument that $1<0$ and $1=0$ are impossible ? This proof easily can be modified to a proof for $\frac{1}{2}>0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a roundabout proof.

First prove that any nonzero real number squared is positive. This can be shown easily by taking two cases: squaring a positive number and showing it's positive, and squaring a negative number and showing it's positive.

Once you have done this, note that $1/4 = (1/2)^2$ so we know that $1/4 > 0$

Also see that $1/2 = 1/4 + 1/4$; that is, $1/2$ is the sum of two positive numbers, which must also be positive

Answer (score 4):

Well, you would have to use more than just "trichotomy".  In particular, you would have to use the **definition** of "1/2"!

I would be inclined to say that, since 1> 0, 1+ 1= 2> 1+ 0= 1> 0 so 2 is positive. And then, dividing both sides of 1> 0 by the **positive** number, 2, 1/2> 0.